# Problems with translation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I have a Problem using the Qt translation:

In a tableView with I'm using a Delegate to get a Combo Box as Edit function:

```
this->gndDelegate = new GenderDelegate(this);
ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(AthleteModel::GENDER_COLUMN, this->gndDelegate);
```

The ComboBox hast to values, which I want to translate with the `tr()` command.
All other Translations works fine, but this two added Items aren't translated:

```
QWidget *GenderDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem    &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
QComboBox *cmbBox = new QComboBox(parent);
cmbBox->addItem(tr("male"), "male");
cmbBox->addItem(tr("female"), "female");

return cmbBox;
}
```

A representation in the qm file exists for this two values

Thanks for your help ...

Comment: This doesn't relate to your actual question, but gender is not a binary. :|

Comment: Does tr("male") work if you do it in a different place of your code?

Comment: Maybe your translation file didn't update properly? Try lrelease on your poject

Comment: Also important thing. When do you create your delegate and when do you install translator?

Comment: The translator is installed before creating the delegate
In other Classe the translator works without problems
I have created the qm file 3 times, so I think the translationfile itself is ok ...

Comment: @Pacnos try qApp->translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the directive Q_OBJECT in your delegate implementation. E.g:

```
class KeyConfigurationDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT //Add This directive !!!

public:
    explicit KeyConfigurationDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~KeyConfigurationDelegate();

    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;

    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;

    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

private:

    QStringList list;
    QStringListModel model;
};
```

Comment: Just a quick note: Make sure to format your code blocks with 4 spaces before each line of code